# Disable Legend Click Event for ExtJs Bar Charts

Tags: extjs

I need to disable the default behavior for legend click which show/hides the chart element. 
I tried doing this but its not working. I tried code like

```
Ext.each(chart.legend.items, function(item) {
item.un("mousedown", item.events.mousedown.listeners[0].fn);
})
```

But its not working in ExtJs 4.2

Please let me know if anyone have done this before.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the scope in your `un` call. It requires a reference to the same function and the same scope to work ([docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-removeListener)). So, this should unregister the mouse listener:

```
Ext.each(chart.legend.items, function(item) {
    item.un("mousedown", item.events.mousedown.listeners[0].fn, item);
});
```

But that probably won't work because the legend items are recreated each time the chart is redrawn. Here's an override that adds a `clickable` option to `Ext.chart.Legend`.

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.chart.LegendItem.Unclickable', {
    override: 'Ext.chart.LegendItem'

    ,onMouseDown: function() {
        if (this.legend.clickable !== false) {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }

    ,onMouseOver: function() {
        if (this.legend.clickable !== false) {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }

    ,onMouseOut: function() {
        if (this.legend.clickable !== false) {
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }
});

Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
    // ...
    legend: {
        clickable: false
    }
});
```